# Signature on LaTex lines Problem

Tags: signatures

How can I put the lines centered with the names and with the same length (the length of the widest name for all)? Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}


\newcommand\namegroup[1]{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    \vspace*{1.5cm}  % leave some space above the horizontal line
    \hrule
    \vspace{1mm} % just a bit more whitespace below the line
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
        #1
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

APROVADO: 5 de Dezembro de 2017.

\begin{center}
    \namegroup{Prof.$^a$ Daniele Cristiane Menezes\\(UFV)}
    \hspace{1.5cm}
    \namegroup{Prof.$^a$ Rita de Cássia Superbi de Sousa\\(UFV)}

    \namegroup{Prof. Emilio Borges\\(Orientador)\\(UFV)}
    \hspace{1.5cm}
    \namegroup{Prof.$^a$ Rejane de Castro Santana\\ (Presidente da banca e coordenadora da disciplina) \\(UFV)}


\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: lines problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a (semi)automatic version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{signatures}
\newlength{\signaturewidth}

\newenvironment{approbation}[1]
 {%
  % reset the counter for the number of signatures
  \setcounter{signatures}{0}%
  % go to vertical mode and insert a minipage
  \par\noindent
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  % first the header
  APROVADO: #1\par
  % followed by some vertical space
  \vspace{3\baselineskip}%
 }
 {%
  % we want to have flexible glue on other side
  % in order to center the last signature, if alone
  \setlength{\leftskip}{0pt plus 1fil}%
  \setlength{\rightskip}{0pt plus 1fil}%
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}%
  % at this point we have gathered the signatures, let's print them;
  % \par will remove the trailing \hfill if there's an odd number of signatures
  \signatures\par
  \end{minipage}\par
 }
\newcommand{\signature}[1]{%
  % measure the width of the current signature
  \measuresignature{#1}%
  % add the signature as argument to \makesignature
  \appto{\signatures}{\makesignature{#1}}%
  % count them
  \stepcounter{signatures}%
  \ifodd\value{signatures}%
    % place \hfill after the odd-numbered signatures
    \appto{\signatures}{\hfill}%
  \else
    % place \par\bigskip after the even-numbered signatures
    \appto{\signatures}{\par\bigskip}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\measuresignature}[1]{%
  % get the width
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}%
  % if the stored value up to now is less than the current one, update
  \ifdim\dimen0>\signaturewidth \signaturewidth=\dimen0 \fi
}
\newcommand{\makesignature}[1]{%
  % make a tabular as wide as \signaturewidth
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \makebox[\signaturewidth]{}\\
  \hline
  #1
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{approbation}{5 de Dezembro de 2017}
\signature{Prof.\textsuperscript{a} Daniele Cristiane Menezes\\(UFV)}
\signature{Prof.\textsuperscript{a} Rita de Cássia Superbi de Sousa\\(UFV)}
\signature{Prof. Emilio Borges\\(Orientador)\\(UFV)}
\signature{Prof.\textsuperscript{a} Rejane de Castro Santana\\
           (Presidente da banca e \\ coordenadora da disciplina) \\(UFV)}
\end{approbation}

\bigskip

\begin{approbation}{5 de Dezembro de 2017}
\signature{Prof.\textsuperscript{a} Daniele Cristiane Menezes\\(UFV)}
\signature{Prof.\textsuperscript{a} Rita de Cássia Superbi de Sousa\\(UFV)}
\signature{Prof. Emilio Borges\\(Orientador)\\(UFV)}
\end{approbation}

\bigskip

\begin{approbation}{5 de Dezembro de 2017}
\signature{Prof.\textsuperscript{a} Daniele Cristiane Menezes\\(UFV)}
\signature{Prof.\textsuperscript{a} Daniele Cristiane Menezes\\(UFV)}
\signature{Prof.\textsuperscript{a} Daniele Cristiane Menezes\\(UFV)}
\end{approbation}

\end{document}
```

You are responsible, though, that the maximum width doesn't exceed half of the textwidth.

[image]